# Does any such smart contract exist where the creator's private key is not required at the time of unlocking?

Tags: contract-development

Is the following type of smart contract possible, and if so, what is it called?

1. Party A creates a smart contract with available funds for a secondary party and signs the transaction
2. Party B enters the correct the parameters to "unlock" the funds (parameters which are in no way related to Party A's private key) and signs the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the goal, the trick is to work out the exchange of a secret, off-chain. It has to be off-chain or else everyone else will see it.

When someone arrives with knowledge of that secret, they can gain access to something. Here's a simple solution that handles many secrets and prizes in-flight. It might give you some ideas.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

contract Secrets {
    
    mapping(bytes32 => uint) public secrets;
    
    function remit(bytes32 secret) public payable {
        secrets[secret] += msg.value;
    }
    
    function claim(bytes32 magic) public {
        bytes32 secret = keyGen(msg.sender, magic);
        uint amount = secrets[secret];
        require(amount > 0, "There is no money for you.");
        secrets[secret] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
    
    function keyGen(address a, bytes32 magic) public pure returns(bytes32 secret) {
        secret = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, magic));
    }
    
}
```

1. Sender makes a key with `keyGen` (off-chain, because it's `pure`).
2. Sender uses the key to send money to the contract (on-chain).
3. Sender gives the secret to the receiver, (somehow, off-chain, e.g. SMS)
4. Receiver uses the key to get the money (on-chain).

Very simplified code to illustrate the point. Not production-ready. ;-)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Forgive my stupid question, but who pays for the unlocking of the funds? The creator or the receiver of them?

Comment: Unlocking will be paid by the receiver because the function is set up so only they can call it. Whoever sends the transaction pays the gas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.26;

contract MyContract {
    address public partyB;

    constructor(address _partyB) public payable {
        partyB = _partyB;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        require(msg.sender == partyB);
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand your goal though, since PartyA can simply transfer those funds directly to PartyB. In other words, why should PartyA be bothered with deploying a contract, and PartyB be bothered with calling a function on that contract?

Comment: I'm after something where Party X is not defined on construction of the contract. Where the funds are released to Party X if the inputs provided by Party X meet a certain condition. Party X could be anyone that is able to fulfil a condition unrelated to Party A's identity.

Comment: @wild_nothing: In the answer above, the condition is PartyB's private key, which is unrelated to PartyA's identity, exactly as you've stated in your question!